# How do I validate an attr based on whether a checkbox is checked in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I want to validate the presence of a `shipping_address` unless it's the same as the billing address. I wrote a `attr_writer` for it. I want to initialise with object with this attr checked.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_writer :ship_to_billing_address
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :billing_address, :shipping_address

  validates :shipping_address, presence: true, unless: -> { self.ship_to_billing_address? }

  def ship_to_billing_address
    @ship_to_billing_address = true if @ship_to_billing_address.nil?
    @ship_to_billing_address
  end

  def ship_to_billing_address?
    ship_to_billing_address
  end
end
```

Here's the form:

```
# Use my shipping address as billing address.
= f.check_box :ship_to_billing_address
```

This doesn't work, however. The form submits 0 and 1 for the values. So I changed the method to this:

```
  def ship_to_billing_address?
    ship_to_billing_address == 1 ? true: false
  end
```

Then to this just to see if validations still kick in, and they still do...

```
  def ship_to_billing_address?
    true
  end
```

But the validations are still kicking in even when it returns false.

After three hours I out of ways for fixing this...

Answer (score 4):

By default, `check_box` returns a String, so `'1'` or `'0'` rather than `1` or `0`. Bear that in mind when testing the value. Here's the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-check_box).

I would also probably change the `attr_writer` to `attr_accessor` and skip the other methods, so something like

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :ship_to_billing_address
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :billing_address, :shipping_address

  validates :shipping_address, presence: true,
                               unless: -> { ship_to_billing_address > '0' }
end
```

I'm also not sure about the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` call -- are the `:billing_address` and `:shipping_address` children objects or just attributes?

Comment: Thanks! I just realised that I need to use a `reject_if: condition` on `accepts_nested_attributes_for` otherwise they validation will always kick in. This makes it a bit more complicated...

Comment: It's `Order belongs_to :shipping_address` and same for billing address... both map to `Address`

Comment: Wouldn't `ship_to_billing_address > '0'`  raise an argument error for comparing a fixnum with a string?

Comment: It should not. `ship_to_billing_address` will be assigned the value from the checkbox, so a String by default.

I've also modified my answer with `attr_accessible` instead of `attr_accessor` - this way you can assign the value like with any other attribute.